# how to turn loop (for) into promise in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

i have implement the java script for request data to the server using ajax (xhr).

but somehow, the loop are not promise.

i tried to implement Promise but alway failed.

this is the javascript what i want to convert into promise

```
    var resulA = ajaxA(a);
    For(resultA){
       var resultB = ajaxB(url?param1=resultA.id);
       for(resultB){

           var resultC = ajaxC(url?param1=resultA.id¶m2=resultB.id);
           for(resultC){
           }

        } 
    }
```

could you please give me a guide how to turn the javascript above into Promise ??

edited: 
here the java script that i want to use promise

```
var xhr = $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/someURL.action?');
        console.log("after load ajax");
xhr.done(function(data){

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


         var xhrPolygon =            $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Koordinat/getKoordinateAja.action?idArea='+data[i].id);
                      xhrPolygon.done(function(resultData){
if(resultData.length>0){
                             for (var j = 0; j < resultData.length; j++) {
                                    var koordinat = [resultData[j].areaLng,resultData[j].areaLat];
                                    console.log(koordinat);
                             }
                            }
                        }); 



}
});
```

Comment: You should have some errors showing up in your console.

Comment: Please note: Java and Javascript are not the same language, in the same way that Austria and Australia are not the same country.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call); some of the answers there talk about how to handle a bunch of promises either in series (one after another) or in parallel (all at once, waiting for them all to finish).

Comment: @PeterMader thankyou for correction, my wrong.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we don't even know what it's supposed to do? [mcve]s shouldn't contain syntax errors. If `ajaxA` is some kind of pseudo-code, please explain what it does. Does it return a promise?

Comment: @Script47 : I don't even know how the Promise get data from previous promise and used it for parameter to get data to the web server using ajax in the next promise.

Answer (score 0):

javascript xhr isn't build on top of promises, but the new fetch does here you have documentation https://github.github.io/fetch/

if you need to create a promise here you have some code

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if(success){
     resolve();
   }
   else{
    reject()
}
});

promise.then(r => console.log(r), e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: then, more than 1 promise, let say Promise A and Promise B, promise B required some of properti on result from Promise A, how to pass the result of Promise A to te Promise B and use it from promise B function.

Comment: promise.then( r => {
    //do something
    console.log(r, 'A');
    return r;
})
.then( r => {
    //do something
    console.log(r, 'B');
    return r;
})
.then( r => {
    //do something
    console.log(r, 'c');
    return r;
});

Comment: you need to return the response of the promise